# Inserting Data in Multiple Tables in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have been stuck on this all day. I have a form making a POST to the API and I want the data to be saved into 3 tables.

1. Records are saved in one table (**Squad**) that has auto generated Id. At insert in this table I want to read the auto generated Id of records and insert those in a different table (**SquadPlayers**) plus also insert an extra field that was submitted by the form in this 2nd table (**SquadPlayers**: *GenericPlayerId*).
2. Also a bit about what I want to submit from the front end form. I want all info about the squad plus Ids for upto 11 players submitted (these ids are what I will like to save in the field *GenericPlayerId* filed for **SquadPlayers** table).

I am new to backend coding especially databases and this new stack I picked up for learning purposes so if you are seeing anything silly here, now you know why :-) So if you think I am totally off or wrong with the my database design let me know. 
[image]

So far I have this in my two classes for Squad and SquadPlayers.

**Squad.java**

```
package com.FUT.track.web.FUTtrackapplication.squads;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Squad")
public class Squad {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private int squadId;
    private String squadName;
    private String squadDescription;
    private String primaryFormation;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "playerId")
    private SquadPlayers squadPlayers;


    public Squad() {

    }

    public Squad(String squadName, String squadDescription, String primaryFormation, SquadPlayers squadPlayers) {
        super();
        this.squadName = squadName;
        this.squadDescription = squadDescription;
        this.primaryFormation = primaryFormation;
        this.squadPlayers = squadPlayers;

    }

    public int getSquadId() {
        return squadId;
    }

    public void setSquadId(int squadId) {
        this.squadId = squadId;
    }

    public String getSquadName() {
        return squadName;
    }

    public void setSquadName(String squadName) {
        this.squadName = squadName;
    }

    public String getSquadDescription() {
        return squadDescription;
    }

    public void setSquadDescription(String squadDescription) {
        this.squadDescription = squadDescription;
    }

    public String getPrimaryFormation() {
        return primaryFormation;
    }

    public void setPrimaryFormation(String primaryFormation) {
        this.primaryFormation = primaryFormation;
    }

    public SquadPlayers getSquadPlayers() {
        return squadPlayers;
    }

    public void setSquadPlayers(SquadPlayers squadPlayers) {
        this.squadPlayers = squadPlayers;
    }

}
```

**SquadPlayers.java**

```
 package com.FUT.track.web.FUTtrackapplication.squads;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="SquadPlayers")
public class SquadPlayers {

    @Id
    private Integer playerId;
    private Integer squadId;
    private Integer genericPlayerId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "squadPlayers")
    private Squad squad;

    public Integer getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(Integer playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public Integer getSquadId() {
        return squadId;
    }

    public void setSquadId(Integer squadId) {
        this.squadId = squadId;
    }


    public Squad getSquad() {
        return squad;
    }

    public void setSquad(Squad squad) {
        this.squad = squad;
    }

    public Integer getGenericPlayerId() {
        return genericPlayerId;
    }

    public void setGenericPlayerId(Integer genericPlayerId) {
        this.genericPlayerId = genericPlayerId;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exception do you have when you run your code?

Comment: @O.Badr When I submit my form Squad table in database should have data for all properties you see above (submitted from the form )and right after it should take the auto generated Ids for the records from Squad table and all player Ids submitted from the form and save in Squad Players. I had the simple save working with one table. Now that I have broken down the structure into multiple tables I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: you should do a fetch after first insert is successful if not throw an exception , use @transactional in service method, create separate service class methods and repository interfaces ...

Comment: could you define whats the relation between **Player** and **Squad** ? I mean in general for your business can a player be assigned in multiple squad ? I am trying to verify your entity mapping. Give your `Player` entity also.

Comment: One more thing. Its seems from you entity that **One Squad will have only one player** ! is that so ?? Clear your business first.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud Ok so that is how it works. There is a generic list of players in "Player" table. A player from this list can be used in any squad but that particular player within the squad is unique. This is not a real world scenario. For learning purposes I'm creating this based on a video game. So say there is a player by the name John, his generic info is saved in Player table. But within a squad John needs to have it's own unique ID so I can track this particular's stats. Does it make sense? I have updated the database diagram in my question, there is another table. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: okay. make sense. its very possible in JPA. showing you how to do this. stay tuned...

Comment: What is the purpose of the genericPlayerId? It looks to me almost as if it is intended to function as the primary-key of the squad_player table, when I look at your diagram up at the top.

Comment: for "playerId" is your db column also named exactly "playerId" so you don't need to specify which column the playerId references in Squad.java?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming this is how you want to have your data flow execution

- You have predefined list of `player`. And a `player` could belong to multiple squad uniquely
- You will create a `squad` on a form submission by assigning `player`s to it. And a assigned player will have a unique identification number.
- Every `squadPlayer` will have `playerStat`

**Note:**

- Relation between `Player` and `Squad` is **ManyToMany**
- Your `SquadPlayer` is the *joining table* between `Player` and `Squad`
- So, Relation between `Player` and `SquadPlayer` is **OneToMany**
- And Relation between `Squad` and `SquadPlayer` is **OneToMany**

**Player**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String position;
    private String country;
    private String club;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player")
    private Set<SquadPlayer> squadSet = new HashSet<>();

    ....
}
```

Here your `Player` entity has **OneToMany** association with `squadSet` field that depicts the fact *a player can be included  in multiple squad*.

**Squad**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="squad")
public class Squad {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String primaryFormation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "squad", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<SquadPlayer> playerSet = new HashSet<>();

    ...
 }
```

And here `Squad` entity has **OneToMany** association with `playerSet` field depicts a Squad could have multiple players. Note unlike the `Player` entity here **OneToMany** annotation defines the cascade type of `Merge` and `Persist`. This tells hibernate to **persist this relation** too when persisting Squad.

**SquadPlayer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "squad_player")
public class SquadPlayer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "generic_player_id")
    private int genericPlayerId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "squad_id")
    private Squad squad;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    private Player player;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "squadPlayer", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private PlayerStat playerStat;

    ...
}
```

Simply here having the other end of mapping for both `Player` and `Squad` with respective joining column

Now your `PlayerStat` entity has **OneToOne** relation with **SquadPlayer**. Having `orphanRemoval=true` will remove the entry from `PlayerStat` when a `SquadPlayer` is removed (though its optional). We also defined the cascading rules for this relation.

**PlayerStat**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player_stat")
public class PlayerStat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private int performance;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "squad_player_id")
    private SquadPlayer squadPlayer;
    ...
}
```

**Persist Squad and all this Relations**

Remember JPA or Hibernate determines your database relationships with the object graph. And the entities persist along with cascading relations from defining their assciations. So this is the flow that you can follow to make proper assocaiton for `Squad` object

- Create a `new Squad()` and set all field with provided fields.
- As you got the list of player id from the *form*, pull those `player` objects within same transaction
- iterate all those `player` and create `new SquadPlayer()` for each. Set all associated fields along with `PlayerStat` field. Then add each `SquadPlayer` to the `Squad` object's `playerSet` field.
- Finally Persist the `Squad` object

If you follow all in this flow your database should populate all tables with proper relations.

**For Further Reading:**

- Understanding the Relationship Mapping see this [OneToMany](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), [ManyToMany](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), [ManyToOne](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-manytoone-association-using-a-non-primary-key-column/) and [OneToOne](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) quick guides
- A good article to start with [JPA and Hibernate Cascade Types](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)
- Another good article about [Cascading Best Practices](https://dzone.com/articles/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-jpa-and)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I will go through this and let you know how it works out. Thanks again.

Comment: It will take a little while as I'm learning all this stuff, I'll keep you posted. Lot of information to absorb and fully understand.

Comment: Updated answer with some preferred articles about entity mapping and cascading. Hope you will find it helpful

Comment: I would also have added a unique constraint in the SquadPlayer entity.
@Table(name = "squad_player", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "squad_id", "player_id" })})

This will allow your DB to automatically enforce that a player cannot belong to the same squad multiple times.

Comment: yes, @NathanKummer . certainly this contraint could be enforced. But I was just intended to focus on the **relationship mapping** and **cascading** things that he was basically stuck in. But I think your notes will help too.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud Moving along with this, it was a lot for me to digest coming from Front End side. Also my fulltime job took over. Finally have time and I was able to implement all this but I have this error now: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [squad_players] contains physical column name [player_id] referred to by multiple physical column names: [player_id], [playerId] 

Any ideas?

Comment: @sayayin as the error messages states `[player_id] referred to by multiple physical column names: [player_id], [playerId] `. This depicts in your physical database table you have two columns names `player_id` and `playerId`. I guess this is because you didnt deleted your previous table. Hence it makes Hibernate confused

Comment: @ShafinMahmud I had actually a lot more errors going on, I have solved the issue now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: our hibernate configuration does not use @Entity annotations in the java. We are using .hbm.xml files. How would we reference an attribute of an object that exists in another table?

Answer (score 1):

I would change the structure in the following way:

1 - Remove altogether the SquadPlayers table and go for a simple oneToMany relationship between player and squad => add fk on player referencing squadId so that a player can be a part of only one squad at a time (make that nullable if there are players without a squad)

2 - for recording result and performance purpose i would change the pk of PlayerStats table to a composite Pk (playerId-SquadId) with both column being Fk too referencing player and squad => you can have multiple performance stats about a player in different squads.

Does it makes sense or i missed some busisness logic that you needed?

P.s. jpa-wise you should be using @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations on your entity for this kind of table structure

Player

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Player")
public class Player {

    @Id
    private Integer playerId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "playerSquadId", referencedColumnName = "squadId")
    private Squad squad;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player")
    private List<PlayerStats> playerStats ;
```

Squad

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Squad")
public class Squad {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Integer squadId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "squad")
    private List<Player> players;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "squad")
    private List<PlayerStats> playerStats ;
```

PlayerStats

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PlayerStats")
public class PlayerStats {

    @Id
    private Integer playerId;
    @Id
    private Integer squadId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "playerStatsPlayerId", referencedColumnName = "playerId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Player player;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "playerStatsSquadId", referencedColumnName = "squadId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Squad squad;
```